# Flume NoSuchMethodError pulling Twitter data into HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, twitter, hdfs, flume-ng

I can't manage to pull Twitter data using Flume into HDFS due to an error I cant't get rid of.

command :

```
bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f conf/twitter.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n TwitterAgent
```

console :

```
2020-12-14 11:38:08,662 (conf-file-poller-0) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:154)] Unhandled error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean twitter4j.conf.Configuration.isStallWarningsEnabled()'
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl.<init>(TwitterStreamImpl.java:60)
    at twitter4j.TwitterStreamFactory.<clinit>(TwitterStreamFactory.java:40)
    at org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.configure(TwitterSource.java:110)
    at org.apache.flume.conf.Configurables.configure(Configurables.java:41)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:325)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:105)
    at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:145)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

flume-env.sh :
I added manually the flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar into flume/lib.

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
 export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms500m -Xmx2000m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
# export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.flume.log.rawdata=true -Dorg.apache.flume.log.printconfig=true "

FLUME_CLASSPATH="/home/jb/flume/lib/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

twitter.conf :

```
# Naming the components on the current agent. 
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter 
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel 
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS
  
# Describing/Configuring the source 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xxx 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = xxx 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xxx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = tutorials point,java, bigdata, mapreduce, mahout, hbase, nosql
  
# Describing/Configuring the sink 

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/user/Hadoop/twitter_data/
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.minBlockReplicas = 1
 
# Describing/Configuring the channel 
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory 
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 100 
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
  
# Binding the source and sink to the channel 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
```

OS: Ubuntu
Flume: v1.9.0
Hadoop: v3.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it works. For those who want to know, please read this.

Firstly, change the Flume version. I use now flume 1.7.0 https://flume.apache.org/releases/1.7.0.html. But maybe a newer version would work, I don't want to break it down :)

Secondly, clone this repo https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example. Inside, there is a flume.conf file. I configured it like that :

```
 # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.


# The configuration file needs to define the sources, 
# the channels and the sinks.
# Sources, channels and sinks are defined per agent, 
# in this case called 'TwitterAgent'

TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = xx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xx
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords =  hadoop, bigdata
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.locations = -54.5247541978, 2.05338918702, 9.56001631027, 51.1485061713
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.language = fr

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/user/Hadoop/twitter_data/%Y/%m/%d/%H/
#It specifies the File format. File formats that are currently supported are SequenceFile, DataStream or CompressedStream.
#The DataStream will not compress the output file and please don’t set codeC. The CompressedStream requires set hdfs.codeC with an available codeC
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
# It specifies the suffix to append to file. For  eg, .avro 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileSuffix = .json
#It specifies the number of events written to file before it is flushed to HDFS.
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 10000
# It specifies the file size to trigger roll, in bytes. If it is equal to 0 then it means never roll based on file size.
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
#It specifies the number of events written to the file before it rolled. If it is equal to 0 then it means never roll based on the number of events.
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 0
#It specifies the number of seconds to wait before rolling the current file. If it is equal to 0 then it means never roll based on the time interval.
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 60
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.callTimeout = 180000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 1000
```

Then, modifie the pom.xml (the version):

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Package-it with maven

```
cd flume-sources
mvn package
```

It creates a target/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Copy it to your <YOUR_FLUME_HOME>/lib

```
cp ./target/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ~/flume/lib
```

I changed the CLASSPATH in the file I showed earlier talked to :

```
FLUME_CLASSPATH="/home/jb/flume/lib/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

Copy the conf/flume.conf we just write into <YOUR_FLUME_HOME>/conf

Thirdly, verify if lib/ twitter4j-core.jar, media-support.jar et stream.jar are in version 3.0.3. If not go download them.

An finally :

```
cd $FLUME_HOME
bin/flume-ng agent --conf ./conf/ -f ./conf/flume.conf -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -n TwitterAgent
```

Halleluja :

```
2020-12-18 02:48:38,805 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:173)] Processed 100 docs
2020-12-18 02:48:40,777 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:173)] Processed 200 docs
2020-12-18 02:48:42,017 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:173)] Processed 300 docs
2020-12-18 02:48:44,772 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:173)] Processed 400 docs
2020-12-18 02:48:46,779 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:173)] Processed 500 docs
2020-12-18 02:48:47,875 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:173)] Processed 600 docs
2020-12-18 02:48:49,852 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:173)] Processed 700 docs
2020-12-18 02:48:52,789 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:173)] Processed 800 docs
2020-12-18 02:48:54,791 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:173)] Processed 900 docs
2020-12-18 02:48:56,805 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.onStatus(TwitterSource.java:173)] Processed 1 000 docs
2020-12-18 02:48:56,805 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.logStats(TwitterSource.java:295)] Total docs indexed: 1 000, total skipped docs: 0
2020-12-18 02:48:56,805 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.logStats(TwitterSource.java:297)]     47 docs/second
2020-12-18 02:48:56,805 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.logStats(TwitterSource.java:299)] Run took 21 seconds and processed:
2020-12-18 02:48:56,806 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.logStats(TwitterSource.java:301)]     0,013 MB/sec sent to index
2020-12-18 02:48:56,807 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.logStats(TwitterSource.java:303)]     0,266 MB text sent to index
2020-12-18 02:48:56,807 (Twitter4J Async Dispatcher[0]) [INFO - org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource.logStats(TwitterSource.java:305)] There were 0 exceptions ignored:
```